# awk for multiple pattern search & remove the first line from the output at the same time

Tags: awk

I need to remove the first line of my output to be removed with awk. Below is the command and output has been displayed..

```
bash-3.2$ ldaplist -l hosts mylv104 | awk -F: '/cdsLocationDetail|.seemac.com|ipHostNumber/ {print $2}'
 cn=mylv104+ipHostNumber=196.2.16.181,ou=hosts,ou=corp,ou=services,o=seemac.com
 R3/C12/U21
 mylv104.seemac.com
 196.2.16.181
```

Though i got it with another awk with pipe but i don't want that..

```
bash-3.2$ ldaplist -l hosts mylv104 | awk -F: '/cdsLocationDetail|.seemac.com|ipHostNumber/ {print $2}' |awk 'NR>1'

 R3/C12/U21
 mylv104.seemac.com
 196.2.16.181
```

Comment: Those two outputs are the same.

Comment: @EtanReisner corrected the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a flag when a line is matched, as shown below:

```
ldaplist -l hosts mylv104 | awk -F: '/cdsLocationDetail|.seemac.com|ipHostNumber/{if(!firstMatch){firstMatch=1;next;}print $2}'
```

Comment: above code works fine, can you explain the below code line

`(!firstMatch){firstMatch=1;next;}`

Comment: change to `...{print "#dbg: firstMatch=" firstMatch; if(!firstMatch)...` to see what is happening. There are multiple terms for such an idea, but it is often called a `flag` variable. Good luck.